# What happened to Anko after the war?

Tags: naruto

I know she gets fat and eats a lot of Dango, but does anything else show up to let us know what happens to her after the war?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in Boruto's anime series, set 10 years after the Fourth Shinobi War, she is part of three arcs till now.

1)Academy Arc :

She is shown to be a instructor at Konoha's academy.She is shown to be yelling at Boruto's class, after they skip Shino's lecture to see the fight between Boruto and Iwabe (another student).

2) School Trip Arc :

When a class trip for Academy is set for Kirigakure (Blood Mist Village),she decides to accompany Shino to look after the students.
They meet Kagura, chosen to be the seventh Mizukage, and Chojuro the sixth and current Mizukage.

They later meet Mei, the fifth Mizukage, and discuss the growing conflict between the land of water and neighbouring countries.

3) Graduation Arc :

For graduation, it is decided that in the practical/ final test, the class would have to face off against Shino, Anko & Konohamaru.

Anko was seen to be putting many students under genjutsu. She also faced up Ino- Shika- Cho trio, testing their willingness to work together, as only one of them would be allowed to pass.

Outside of these three arcs, there has been little development of the character.